# Subscripts position in \sum and \sup

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I am trying to write the following formula

[image]

I have written this code on Overleaf but I don't like the result

```
\[   
||u||_{\ell^p} = 
     \begin{cases}
       \big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |u_n|^p\big)^{\frac{1}{p}}, &\quad\text{αν}\quad 0<p<\infty\\
       \sup_{-\infty<n<\infty}|u_n| &\quad\text{αν}\quad p=\infty \\
              \end{cases}
\]
```

[image]

What should I change to have better results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I do not know the packages you are using, I took ordinary `\alpha` and `\nu`. (Does `\alpha\nu` mean "when" or something similar in Greek?)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[   
\|u\|_{\ell^p} = 
     \begin{cases}
       \displaystyle\Bigl(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |u_n|^p\Bigr)^{\frac{1}{p}}, &\quad{\alpha\nu}\quad 0<p<\infty\\
      \displaystyle \sup_{-\infty<n<\infty}|u_n| &\quad{\alpha\nu}\quad p=\infty \\
              \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please observe also the changes for norm and large parentheses.

Comment: thank you that was very helpful

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos You are welcome! Now you may consider upvoting or accepting an answer (sorry for the reminder, but you are relatively new here).

Comment: αν apparently means "if" or something to that extent.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `dcases` from `mathtools` (that also loads `amsmath`).

With the `dcases*` variant the conditions are typeset in text mode. In either variant, the first part is typeset in display math mode.

Note the fine tunings:

1. `\biggl` and `\biggr` for the parentheses
2. `\,` after `\biggl(` in order to avoid a clash
3. `\!` in the exponent (and the slashed form) to push it nearer to the parenthesis
4. `\lVert` and `\rVert` instead of `||`; similarly for `\lvert` and `\rvert` instead of `|` (you can test the difference between `\lvert -u\rvert` and `| -u|`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\lVert u\rVert_{\ell^p} =
\begin{dcases*}
\biggl(\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert u_n\vert^p\biggr)^{\!1/p},
  & αν $0<p<\infty$ \\
\sup_{-\infty<n<\infty}\lvert u_n\rvert,
  & αν $p=\infty$
\end{dcases*}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I found for my tastest this the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

The limits for your `\sum` and `\sum` are displayed to the side because the `cases` environment formats the contents in inline style. To force the limits above and below the operators, you can use `\limits`:

```latex
\[
    \|u\|_{\ell^p} =
    \begin{cases}
        \left( \sum \limits_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} |u_n|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}, &\quad \text{if} \quad 0 < p < \infty\\
        \sup \limits_{-\infty < n < \infty} |u_n|, &\quad \text{if} \quad p = \infty \\
    \end{cases}
\]
```

[image]

Notice how the `\sum` symbol remains about the same size as the absolute value bars, so I believe this is how your first image was typeset.

Also, notice how I changed the `||` to `\|`, as that's a better way to typeset double vertical bars for norms. Also also, I changed the parentheses to `\left( ... \right)`, as this allows the delimiters to automatically resize according to their contents.

With that said, it's easier to just force display style using `\displaystyle`, but note that that increases the size of the `\sum`.